# homology of circle times n-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I would like to compute $H_i(S^1\times S^n;\mathbb{Z})$ for $i\geq3$. I believe one approach is to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

> If we take the admissible cover consisting of $S^1\times S^n\setminus\{N\}\cong S^1\times D^n \cong S^1$ and $S^1\times S^n\setminus\{S\}\cong S^1$, then we have
> $$\dots\to H_i(U)\oplus H_i(V)\to H_i(S^1\times S^n)\to H_{i-1}(S^1\times S^{n-1})\to   H_{i-1}(U)\oplus H_{i-1}(V)\to\dots
> $$
> Since $(S^1\times S^n\setminus\{N\})\cap (S^1\times S^n\setminus\{S\})\cong S^1\times (S^n\setminus\{N\}\cap S^n\setminus\{S\})\cong S^1 \times S^{n-1}$.
> Then we get a sequence of isomorphisms $$H_i(S^1\times S^n;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{i-1}(S^1\times S^{n-1};\mathbb{Z})$$ for $i\geq 3$. We have for $n\geq 3$
> $$H_n(S^1\times S^n;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{2}(S^1\times S^{2};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$$
> and
> $$H_{n+1}(S^1\times S^n;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{2}(S^1\times S^{1};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$$ Now looking at the CW-structure of $S^1\times S^n$, we have that for $2\leq i<n $ and $n+1<i$,
> $$
> H_i(S^1 \times S^n)\cong0.
> $$
> Now, given that $n\geq 3$, the cellular structure looks like
> $$
> \dots \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\to0\dots 0\to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}
> $$
> The inclusion of $S^1$ into $S^1\times \{*\}\subset S^1\times S^n$ induces a chain map from cellular chain complex of $S^1$ to $S^1\times S^n$. The differential $\partial_1$ of cellular chain complex is trivial since $H_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. So similarly $H_1(S^1\times S^n)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. So we have
> $$
> H_i(S^1\times S^n ; \mathbb{Z})=\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} &  i=0,1,n,n+1\\
> 0 & \text{otheriwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Now I cannot verify if I am correct as I did not find any literature source. Also is there more straight forward solution to this problem?

Comment: The Kunneth theorem gives an immediate answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

Comment: The answer looks correct but the Kunneth formula is the fastest way.

Comment: I think it is good to do these computations by hand, which you have done. An alternative way, which still doesn't use machinery like Kunneth but requires less computation, is to study the pair $(S^1 \times S^n, S^1 \vee S^n)$, and use the LES of a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more direct approach in my opinion. Either you know this fact, or alternatively it is exercise 2.2.36 in *Hatcher*: there is a natural isomorphism
$$
H_i(S^d \times X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_i(X;\mathbb{Z}) \oplus H_{i-d}(X;\mathbb{Z})
$$
for any space $X$ and any natural number $d$. Now we take $X = S^n$ and $d=1$. Since we know the homology groups of $S^n$ your result follows. I hope this is helpful!